# Send Parameter and Body row empty retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to call a service, with Retrofit2 Android library, that need:

- Authorization
- Headers
- Parameter
- Body

My interface is like this:

```
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/nameOfAction")
    Call<ItemResponse> callAction(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Field("nameOfParameter") String nameOfParameter);
```

I call it with this code:

```
 ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<CarrelloResponse> call = apiService.callAction( "Bearer " + tokenAccess, "valueOfParameter");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ItemResponse> call, Response<ItemResponse> response) {

                int statusCode = response.code();

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        // code
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, response.errorBody().toString());
                    }
                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ItemResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());

            }
        });
```

But it doesn't work because i need to send also body raw empty for work.

If i send it with Postman, as image below it works:

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `@FormUrlEncoded` and change `@Field` to `@Query` param like this

```
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
})
@POST("/nameOfAction")
Call<ItemResponse> callAction(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Query("nameOfParameter") String nameOfParameter);
```

******** **EDIT BY OP** *******

adding slash at the end of nameOfAction it works changing also @Field to @Query:

```
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("nameOfAction/")
    Call<ItemResponse> callAction(@Header("Authorization") String authorization, @Query("nameOfParameter") String nameOfParameter);
```